# LARAVEL- how do I install a package that requires a previous version?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was looking to install this package - **https://github.com/faustbrian/Laravel-Invoice**  and when doing composer require faustbrian/laravel-invoice  I received an error stating:

*Installation request for faustbrian/laravel-invoice ^1.1 -> satisfiable by faustbrian/laravel-invoice[1.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - faustbrian/laravel-invoice 1.1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* || 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40].
    - illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.15].*

Is there a way to install this package without using an older version of Laravel (in this case 5.4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Just wait the package update to support your current laravel framework or downgrade your laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can wait package upgrade to support laravel 5.6